# XAMPP apache with stand alone MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP to run PHP from eclipse. I have a standalone MySQL server that I use it from another java program. I want the apache server inside XAMPP to use this standalone MySQL instead of the default one. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Given your low accept, rate, I wouldn't expect too many answers...

Comment: I have the same issue. I XAMPP and a standalone mysql in my mac. When i start the apache from XAMPP and the standalone mysql server, the php code in the apache server cannot connect to mysql and throwing exception. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the Xampp-controlpanel you can select the tools to start. If you have installed a standalone mysql-server, it is usually registered as a server (xampp regognizes that!). In you PHP-Application you just have to connect to this server (Address: Localhost and the username/password from your server)

Just dont start the xampp-server, start your own one.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't start XAMPP's MySQL Server. Apache or PHP does nothing else than connecting to localhost and MySQL's standard port.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a conflict, when you try to use one or another MySQL Server, it is a big "chance" to have them both opened.

You can check this by "right-click" on My Computer, and select "Manage". There go to "Services and applications" and you can see which one is running.

If both are running you can stop the one you don't wanna use.

Hope this help.

P.S. You may wanna use WAMPP, because it has a better graphical interface, and much more usefully shortcuts.

Comment: Iam using Mac, so i won't be able to use WAMPP. The main problem that i don't want to use the MySQL instance inside the XAMPP and just use the normal standalone MySQL server but in the same time i must deply my php pages on the XAMPP. I am trying to make a couple of solutions, one of them is changing the configuration file inside etc folder.